# PO files, swap msgid and msgstr

Tags: internationalization, gettext, po

Is there any tool that lets me swap msgid and msgstr in a po file? I couldn't find it.

Notice that I don't really need to keep the resulting msgstrs: in short, I need to get a second po file having as msgids the first file's msgstrs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two useful tools for this purpose:

- http://mola.io/2013/09/17/swapping-languages-in-gettext-po-file/
- http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/poswap.html

Gone offline:

- http://dybdahl.dk/dxgettext/docs/online/msghack.html

Answer (score 0):

I only see reg exp for that, and swapping expressions.